# Why the output is 2 during second fn function call?

Tags: javascript, logic

I came across an Javascript Example but not quite satisfied with the justification or rather confused on scope of `this` inside function. See the example below:

```
var length = 10;
function fn() {
    console.log(this.length);
}

var obj = {
  length: 5,
  method: function(fn) {
    fn();
    arguments[0]();
  }
};

obj.method(fn, 1);
```

First time `10` is logged which is understandable since it is called from global scope. However second time `2` is logged which sort of confused me. I look for an answer and this is what I got -

> We know that we can access any number of arguments in a JavaScript
>   function using the arguments[] array.
>
> Hence arguments0 is nothing but calling fn(). Inside fn now, the
>   scope of this function becomes the arguments array, and logging the
>   length of arguments[] will return 2

Does anyone has a better answer to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `arguments[0]();`

The value of `this` is therefore the same as `arguments`.

The arguments are: `fn, 1`

There are 2 of them.

`arguments.length` is therefore `2`.

Comment: So does it mean all that matters is the caller of the function and not the scope/block where it is called?

Comment: In this case. Yes. Scope has nothing to do with the value of `this` (well, unless you use arrow functions which copy the value of `this` from the scope they are created in).

Comment: Got it. Will keep this in mind. `this` is not that easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Arguments is an array-like object. When you invoke `arguments[0]()`, the function that returns this.length is sitting inside the array-like arguments object. In that context, the keyword *this* refers to the arguments object.

```
arguments: [function fn() { return this.length; }, 1]
arguments[0](); // returns 2;
```

Here's a different example to help illustrate my point:

```
const arr = [1, 2, function() { return this.length }];
console.log(arr[2]()); // 3
```

The third item in the array is a function that, when invoked, returns the length of the array. That is similar to writing arr.length.